# View not attached to window manager -- Service stopped?

Tags: android, android-service, illegalargumentexception, ondestroy, android-windowmanager

My app uses a service to add a persistent overlay onto the screen via a WindowManager:

```
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); 

         wm.addView(ll, ll_lp);
         addNotification();

    }
```

Users receive an error after about 10-15 min of the service running that force closes the app with the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:383)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:285)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
at com.MyApp.MyService.onDestroy(MyService.java:210)
```

Here's the line in MyService:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        wm.removeView(ll);
        removeNotification();
    }
```

I assume what's happening is that Android OS is killing my app and the WM can no longer access the view `ll`? How can I make sure that

1. The overlay persists for longer than 10-15 min and isn't killed off by Android OS
2. I don't receive this error if it does get killed

Comment: Dang no answers at all...

Comment: Still no answers XD

Answer (score 0):

I removed the notification first and then tried to remove a view / caught a possible exception:

```
try
{
    if(ll != null) wm.removeView(ll);
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
    Log.e("myapp", "removed view that is not there");
}
```

Hope this helps somehow!